# CSS table with alternate background color with hidden elements

Tags: html, css, datagrid

I found some approaches to alternete colors using Javascript, but I can hide some elements in my table/datagrid but with this CSS the bg color doesn't alternate correctly:

**CSS**

```
.grid tr:not(.display-none):nth-child(2n+1) > td {
    background: red;
}
.display-none * {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="grid">
    <tr><td>nono1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono4</td></tr>
    <tr class="display-none"><td>nono5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nono8</td></tr>
</table>
```

See the live sample

http://jsfiddle.net/WBn4U/

Comment: Here's some guidance on why `nth-child` doesn't work like this and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32380418/3597276

Comment: [Pusre CSS solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42014074/3094153)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So try

```
<table class="grid">
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono1</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono2</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono3</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono4</td></tr>
    <tr class="display-none"><td>nono5</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono6</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono7</td></tr>
    <tr class="parent"><td>nono8</td></tr>
</table>

.parent:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fff;
        }
        .parent:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: red;
        }

        /* after the first non-.parent, toggle colors */
        tr:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: red;
        }
        tr:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        /* after the second non-.parent, toggle again */
        tr:not(.parent) ~ tr:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        tr:not(.parent) ~ tr:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .display-none * {
            display: none;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vA5Wz/

Comment: It's a nice alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible as the `:nth-child` pseudo class cycles through all children elements. Thus, you cannot exclude an element from the selection - even using `:not` is ineffective.

> [**Selectors Level 3 - 6.6.5. Structural pseudo-classes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos)
>
> Standalone text and other non-element nodes are not counted when calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its parent. When calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its parent, the index numbering starts at 1.

My interpretation is that all **element nodes** are counted in the calculation. By stating that text and other non-element nodes aren't calculated, all element nodes must be calculated, as demonstrated.

---

To solve the problem, I would suggest just removing the element from the document altogether, via JS.

For simplicity, here is some jQuery:

```
$('table.grid tr.display-none').remove();
```

In doing so, you can now achieve the desired results using the following selector:

```
table.grid tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td {
    background: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/FdMU2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/1/

Using jQuery

```
jQuery('tr:visible').filter(':odd').css({'background-color': 'red'});
jQuery('tr:visible').filter(':even').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Hope it helps