# How to toggle elements in and out of DOM using jQuery detach() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a group of divs arranged in a grid.

[image]

To style each div I'm selecting them with the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

```
div.tile:nth-child(4n-7) .text { background-color: yellow; }
```

A user can hide divs by clicking on a button (which fires a jQuery function that adds a `display: none` rule to the `class` attribute in the selected div).

**jQuery**

```
$('.hide-divs').click(function () {
     $('.dolphin').toggleClass('hidden');
    })
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

*Here's the problem:*

Even though `display: none` removes the div from the screen, it doesn't remove the div from the DOM, so the `nth-child` selector still counts it when applying styles, which in turn messes up the visual design of the grid.

[image]

*The above layout is broken because only the first column should be yellow.*

So my first thought was to use the jQuery [`remove()` method](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), which takes elements (and its descendants) out of the DOM.

Turns out, however, once `remove()` is applied you can't get those divs back. They're gone. So the toggle function breaks.

After a bit of research I discovered the jQuery [`detach()` method](https://api.jquery.com/detach/), which does the same thing as `.remove()`, except it stores the removed elements' data for later use.

From the [jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/detach/):

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that
>   `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed
>   elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be
>   reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Everything looks good for `detach()` to work with the toggle switch, except my efforts to implement it aren't working.

I've used the [example on the jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) as a guide but it doesn't work on the grid. I also read various related posts on this site, but to no avail. I must be missing something.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/tfyfpbb2/

```js
$('.hide-divs').click(function() {
  $('.dolphin').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.text {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.tile:nth-child(4n-7) .text {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}
button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">01</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">02</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text dolphin">03</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">04</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">05</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text dolphin">06</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">07</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text dolphin">08</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">09</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">10</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">11</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
      <div class="text">12</div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- end .row -->

  <button type="button" class="hide-divs">HIDE DIVS 3, 6 &amp; 8</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest still using detach.  You can do so with this code:

```
var divs;

$('.hide-divs').on('click', function () {
    if(divs) {
        $(divs).appendTo('.row');
        divs = null;
    } else {
        divs = $('.dolphin').parent().detach();
    }
});
```

Then to ensure that the same order is used, I came up with this bit of code:

```
$('.tile').each(function(i){
    $(this).data('initial-index', i);
});

...

$(divs).each(function(){
    var oldIndex = $(this).data('initial-index');
    $('.tile').eq(oldIndex).before(this);
});
```

Put it all together and we get this code:

```
var divs;

$('.tile').each(function(i){
    $(this).data('initial-index', i);
});

$('.hide-divs').on('click', function () {
    if(divs) {
        $(divs).appendTo('.row').each(function(){
            var oldIndex = $(this).data('initial-index');
            $('.tile').eq(oldIndex).before(this);
        });
        divs = null;
    } else {
        divs = $('.dolphin').parent().detach();
    }
});
```

Demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqbzff2v/2/

Answer (score 3):

Everyone was close, but here is exactly what you are looking for with your current html markup: http://jsfiddle.net/vs5o5nLb/2/

The trick is setting yourself up ahead of time with what you need to actually toggle, then keeping that information around to insert and detach from.

```
var $els = $( '.tile' );
var stack = [];
var isShown = true;

$els.each(function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    if ( $this.find('.dolphin').length ) {
        stack.push({
            $el : $this,
            index : $els.index( this )
        });
    }
});

$('.hide-divs').click(function () {
    if ( isShown ) {
        $.each(stack, function() {
            this.$el.detach();
        });
        isShown = false;
    } else {
        $.each(stack, function() {
            $('.tile').eq( this.index ).before( this.$el );
        });
        isShown = true;
    }
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used remove() with toggle to remove and delete elements. example: each time on mouse hover and check if text is printed in unordered list and then elements are removed on the next click.
Jquery

```
        $('h1').hover(function(){
                //alert('test toggle');
               remove_el();
               for(var i=0;i<5;i++){ 
               $('ul').append('<li>'+'END_check else'+i+'</li>').toggle();

                 }
               }

                );

            function remove_el(){

                $('li').remove();
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very sure if this what you'd like to do - http://jsfiddle.net/tfyfpbb2/1/

If so, you just need to add three row classes instead of one. This way each row has it's own "space" and will not miss up the next row's styling.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="text">01</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
        <div class="text">02</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
        <div class="text dolphin">03</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
        <div class="text">04</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if that's not what you wanted and I can edit my answer.

Comment: This doesn't really work. If you try to hide other divs the layout breaks. http://jsfiddle.net/tfyfpbb2/2/ .. Plus, it doesn't remove the hidden elements from the DOM. Thanks anyway.