# css selector : apply a style on all visible elements only

Tags: css

I have a panel-group with 6 elements :

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       1
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default js_subscription_open hidden">
        3
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
       4
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        5
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make these panels to alternates color (zebra stripe) using CSS only,

So I applied this formula :

```
.panel:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white
}
```

My problem is that I dont want that this formula be applied to the div with the "hidden" class (third div) ... I want to "jump" this div ...

I'm seeking for something like :

```
.panel:not(.hidden):nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white
}
```

but this is not working !! 
Any idea ?

Comment: For `nth-child` to work in this case, you need to remove the hidden div from the DOM. Consider jQuery `remove()` or `detach()`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32385795/3597276

Comment: To put it in simple terms, the 4th child is always the 4th child irrespective of whether the 3rd child is alive or not. Here you selector selects the even numbered children of their parent as long as they also have `.panel` class and not the `.hidden` class. The fourth

Comment: Yes, using JS resolve the issue, thanks Michael_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:nth-child() pseudo-class looks through the children tree of the parent to match the valid child (odd, even). therefore when you combine it with :not(.hidden) it won't filter the elements properly.

you can do one thing as suggested by [hashem qolami in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058442/5326871) which is:

we could fake the effect by CSS gradient as follows:

```css
    .hidden {display:none;}
    
    .panel-group {
      line-height: 1.2em;
      
      background-color: orange; 
      background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, green 50%);
      background-size: 100% 2.4em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       1
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default js_subscription_open hidden">
        3
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
       4
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        5
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use JS to delete the row.

Comment: Yes, but his CSS solution is not really dynamic ... it is just a patch !! .. The JS solution is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with modern CSS (2023). An expansion of the CSS specification allows you to specify the elements that should be counted by the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector using a second selector list, like this: `tr:nth-child(2n of tr.important)`.

The syntax looks like this: `:nth-child(<nth> [of <complex-selector-list>]?)`

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#using_of_selector), this has been supported in all major browsers for about 6 months, since May 2023, when Firefox added support. [W3C CSS WG Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

Example:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)){
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Example of "of   &lt;selector&gt;" use</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Subaru</td><td>Forester</td><td>2021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ford</td><td>Ranger</td><td>2019</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td>Nissan</td><td>Rogue</td><td>2015</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Porche</td><td>911 Turbo</td><td>2023</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td>Toyota</td><td>Corolla</td><td>2009</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Chevy</td><td>Astro</td><td>1999</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

`.panel:not(.hidden):nth-child(even) {
  background: white;
}`

You may not be able to notice what it does if it is on a white background. Also the div that is hidden is an odd numbered child.