# css nth-child or nth-of-type issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The problem is that news4 `div` is 30% wide. It has to be 50%. It looks like `nth-of-type` also counts .advertisement `div` and news4 `div` becomes fifth child element. The same is with `nth-of-type` and `nth-child`.
My html example is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="news">news1</div>
    <div class="news">news2</div>
    <div class="news">news3</div>
    <div class="advertisement">Advertisement</div>
    <div class="news">news4</div>
    <div class="news">news5</div>
    <div class="news">news6</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.container { width: 100%; }
.news:nth-of-type(3n+1) { width: 50%; }
.news:nth-of-type(3n+2) { width: 30%; }
.news:nth-of-type(3n+3) { width: 20%; }
```

Comment: Yes, the `nth-child` always selects nth child under the parent (and not nth child with a specific class). Similarly `nth-of-type` always selects the nth element of a certain type under the parent (and not the nth element of type with a certain class).

Comment: Here's a detailed explanation and possible workaround options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32380418/3597276

Answer (score 1):

`nth-of-type` refers to the element tag (`div`) not the class name (`.news`).

If you want to target the `.news` item after `.advertisement` you might consider the following selector:

```
.advertisement + .news { width: 50%; }
```

Comment: thanks for idea. I have changes .news <div> to <article>