# CSS nth-chid selector without hidden chilld node

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
tr.whois:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<tr class="whois">row 1</tr>
<tr class="whois">row 2</tr>
<tr class="hide">row 3</tr>
<tr class="whois">row 4</tr>
<tr class="whois">row 5</tr>
```

here visible row (1,2,4,5) and `nth-chid(even)` makes black (1,3,5)-

[image]

But I need this-

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355054/how-to-get-nth-child-selector-to-skip-hidden-divs

Comment: the answer you accepted doesn't work in all the situations: https://jsfiddle.net/yh82k1qv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

> Since you have `hide` element as well so this is the place where you have to use `~`(negate) for `odd` and `even`
>   The code is pretty straight forward to understand let me know if you need explaination.

```css
.whois {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.whois:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.whois.hide {
  display: none;
}

.whois.hide~.whois:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.whois.hide~.whois:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="whois">
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="whois">
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="whois hide">
    <td>row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="whois">
    <td>row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="whois">
    <td>row 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/yh82k1qv/ it only do for some particular case

Comment: Hmmm I didn't consider this! considering OP data I was able to fix it! do you have any inputs ?

Comment: this is not possible with only CSS, JS is needed